# Android-Volley--Multipart-Request-with-Upload-Progress

Tags: android, android-volley, multipartentity

[The transferred() function in the listener is called very fast up to 100% in seconds, but the images upload takes minutes ..
Does anybody know how to resolve this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPpI6.png)

My Git Repository

https://github.com/fatahzull/Android-Volley--Multipart-Request-with-Upload-Progress.git

Comment: did you manage to do that?